# Need Help re-positioning JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield

My GUI interface is displaying the `JTextFields` beside the `JLabels`. I want them to go under.

```
Username [Jtextfield]
```

I want the `JTextField` to go under the `username`, which is the same as on the east side of the panel.

Comment: you should use a layout manager for panelWest

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for `panelWest`, which allows you to place components on top of each other:

```
panelWest.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelWest, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

Comment: ok thanks peeps! will keep this in reference. i fixed it by using gridlayout